# Stellar.js giving uncaught type error

Tags: jquery, parallax, typeerror, stellar.js

I'm trying to implement stellar.js into my site to add a parallax effect to a div with a background image. The div has a class "header-wrapper", I've followed everything to the letter as far as I can see, yet nothing is happening. Can anyone see any glaringly obvious reason why this might not work? Here is the Js that I am using:

```
$(function(){
    $('.header-wrapper').stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalOffset: 40
    });
});
```

And the error being returned is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stellar' of undefined
```

The site in question is here: http://www.skizzar.com/chadedwards and the parallax effect should be applied to the image at the top of the page. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is jQuery correctly loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` doesn't refer to jQuery; perhaps the Google AJAX page doesn't automatically export this, or you've disabled this somewhere mannually (using [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

Use `jQuery.stellar`. All or almost all of your code seems to use `jQuery` and not `$`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that this does make a change, but the parallax effect is still not loading. Do you have any other advice on this?